# why two border showing on hover of input field?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-design, material-ui, jss

could you please tell me why two border showing on hover of input field ?
see my image 
[image]

I am using `react+ material` with react .
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/kxx08jo487

I want only one border `red` .I tried like that

```
root: {
    '&>div': {
      '&:hover': {
        borderBottom: '1px solid red',
      }
    },
  },
```

I take help from this link
https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi joy since  **Material UI** has been evolving rapidly. There are drastic changes in API being reflected in docs. We use formLabel inside formControl to take leverage of JSS.

Here is the working code: [Border Color Customised](https://codesandbox.io/s/z684jo2r8l)

Comment: thanks for answer .sorry for late replay ..your answer is something better ..have you seen when user `hover` the `input` field it show `black` color can we removed that

Comment: can we remove effect from field in all field it's show `black` border .it something theme

Comment: Hi I have added hover changes and updated codesandbox link above in my answer. We need to use `createMuiTheme` to provide same css to all our desired components and wrap our components with `MuiThemeProvide`